# Dynamic navigation in django

Tags: python, django

I want to build a dynamic navigation menu that will fill in automatically based on the database, and will be on every page. For example, I have a Genre model. In this model there is a field called parent. If this is null, it is a top-level genre. Otherwise it holds the id of other genre, and is a subgenre of this genre. It looks like this:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

So I have a CSS dropdown menu and I want to populate it so it goes like this:

Genre -> List of top-level genres. Then for each of these, another drop-down menu of the subgenres of that genre. If that makes sense.

But I have no idea how to implement this in django. I have a context processor, but this just lists all genres as one flat drop-down currently (and I have to remember to add it for every view). I'm not sure if it would be better to use a custom tag or an inclusion tag, or how to do it for this example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about creating a [hierarchy / tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_data_structure), which is rather annoying to deal with.

Look into Modified Preorder Tree Traversal, a method for dealing with trees like this.
There's a django app for it!
http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/

I highly recommend using this instead of rolling your own.

Here's a quick tutorial on getting started: so much easier than doing this yourself.
http://komunitasweb.com/2010/09/a-quick-tutorial-on-django-mptt/

---

Otherwise, if you want to support infinite depth, you will need a recursive function that iterates through a `Genre`'s children. Here's an example from the [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) shopping cart. Basically, you'd have to iterate over each top level parent, recursively iterate over its children until there are no more children.

```
def _recurse_for_children(self, node, only_active=False):
    children = []
    children.append(node)
    for child in node.child.active():
        if child != self:
            if (not only_active) or child.active_products().count() > 0:
                children_list = self._recurse_for_children(child, only_active=only_active)
                children.append(children_list)
    return children
```

I would highly recommend looking at satchmo's template tag for rendering these trees to get some ideas.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Another example project, which uses django-mptt underneat, is https://github.com/caktus/django-treenav