# How do I keep one menu across multiple Django apps?

Tags: python, django

I am looking at creating a django-based website that will be have a few extremely different kinds of sections to it. My thought was that these should be separate apps, however I want these to be able to be brought across to different projects.

I am going to have a main menu system that is created from the database. I want all of these different sections of the site to be under this main menu system, and as such, have a standard header.

Most examples online seem to say that you should create a base.html template with the menu and then have everything else inherit from that. My issue is that this doesn't seem very portable as far as the apps are concerned. I would have to make all of the templates inherit from the base.html, which I feel would reduce their portability?

I guess what I am asking is:

**What is the best way to create a persistent main menu system across multiple independent apps in django?**

Comment: What do you mean by portable ? you are talking about HTML right ?! or you mean extensible ?

Comment: I guess the way I was thinking of designing an app was as self-contained (including templates). For example, an app that showed poll results from a separate local database in a small (200p by 200px div) that you can just include in your side-bar as you need it. I'd want to use it in various django projects with no modification. Or is that something you can't do in django?

Comment: Also, the menu is populated from the database, there isn't a flat menu. As such, how do I ensure that the menu is populated in every view?

Comment: So you want to hit the db and fetch the content in every url access .?

Comment: I was planning on it. I am guessing this isn't the best way? The menu would have sections up top and I was planning on allowing users to add and remove these dynamically. How would I show the sections the user has added without fetching the content with every url access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Persistent Menu System

I think the conventional way of doing this would be to, as you said, create a base template for your project. If you want it to be available to multiple apps the easiest way would probably be to put it in a template folder in the project root, i.e. myproject/templates/myproject/base.html. In this template you build your menu system, and then include a block to be overwritten by the child templates:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Next create a template in your app called something like `app_base.html` and simply put in the lines:

```
{% extends "myproject/base.html" %}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

At this point your directory structure should look something like this:

```
myproject/
    myproject/
    app_one/
        templates/
            app_one/
                app_base.html
    templates/
        myproject/
            base.html
```

Then in every subsequent template you create for that app, at the top add the line:

```
{% extends "app_one/app_base.html" %}
```

You may then repeat this for every app you create, and it means you should only have to edit `base.html` when you want to tweak your menu system.

### Portability

The fact that you have created `app_base.html` in each app should allow you to pluck out any one app and drop it into another project, without having to go through every template and change the name of the template it inherits from. Then you can simply edit `app_base.html` to make the layout of the pages fall into line with the structure of your new project. This may be done, for example, either by writing the new layout code directly into this template, or by altering the `extends` line at the top to inherit from the base template for your new site (note that this base template will have to include a `content` block).

Note: When you add the `templates` directory to your project root don't forget to add the line:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

to settings.py so that Django knows where to find the additional templates.

I hope this helps. It was the best solution I could think of, but I feel that it may be  difficult to achieve 100% autonomy with template inheritance in Django, as there is a requirement for child and parent templates to maintain consistent blocks with one another.

Comment: I like this solution, it definitely allows me to move the apps to different projects with only a single line needing to be modified in the app (if that).

Comment: One question though, if my menu in the base.html file needs to be populated from the database, how would I ensure it is populated in every view. Would AJAX be the best bet, or is there a better way to do it in django?

Comment: I think that would probably be your best bet if you're concerned about portability. You could write a view function that simply retrieves and returns the navigation bar data and call it with AJAX when the page loads. An alternative would be to write a python script that pulls the data in, which you then call from every view and pass to the template, but that will be less portable. You may also find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061925/dynamic-navigation-in-django

Answer (score -1):

The best pratice as suggested by the Django Doc is to use a base skeleton and inherit from it in each of your apps or pages, and you can make it "extensible" by overridden blocks.

From django doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

> The most powerful – and thus the most complex – part of Django’s
>   template engine is template inheritance. Template inheritance allows
>   you to build a base “skeleton” template that contains all the common
>   elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can
>   override.

Comment: He said multiple apps. Am I right ?

Comment: Yeah, he can use the same template in all of the apps, is there a problem with that ?